# Tell apart exceptions thrown from a function and from constructor or destructor of its argument

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose there is a function:

```
void f(X x);
```

and it is called like this:

```
f({});
```

(It is assumed that X has a suitable constructor.)

As I understand, expression `f({})` will be compiled to something like this:

1. `x` is constructed
2. `f` is executed
3. `x` is destructed

Then how to tell apart exceptions thrown from `f` itself and exceptions thrown from constructor or destructor of `x`?

```
try {
    f({});
} catch (...) {
    // Where the current exception was thrown from?
}
```

---

Update. Suppose also that the implementations of `f`, `X::X` and `X::~X` cannot be changed and exceptions thrown from them are inherently indistinguishable.

Comment: Why is it important to know what threw the exception? I would tend to say that you should probably try to avoid situations where knowing that would be important.

Also, destructors that throw exceptions are dangerous and should be avoided. Basically, you can't throw two exceptions at once, and since destructors run when exceptions are thrown, it becomes almost impossible to write exception-safe code in the presence of destructors that throw.

Comment: @BenS. it would be inadvisable to write code that required the distinction, but I can see how it would come in very handy during debugging.

Comment: @BenS. `f` might require clean up. If the exception was thrown from the constructor of `x` or from `f` itself, then I should not do the clean up. If the exception was thrown from the destructor of `x` or was not thrown at all, then I should do the clean up.

Comment: @radix, it's probably more advisable to use RAII or try/catch clauses inside of `f` to perform the cleanup.

Comment: @radix Since your update indicates that you're stuck with the implementations here, you'll just have to deal with it in this instance, but as a rule destructors that throw make life very difficult and you should avoid writing them whenever possible. See http://www.369o.com/data/books/Exceptional_Cpp/0201615622_ch16lev1sec1.html for an excerpt from Herb Sutter's "Exceptional C++" that explains the problems in detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the C++ throw statement nor the standard exception constructors capture a stack trace. You cannot determine what threw from within a catch clause unless the thrown object conveys that information.

This could be done by either having `X` and `f` throw an object of a different type (and then you would have two or more catch clauses) or by having them fill an object with enough information to tell the errors apart (for instance, by overriding `std::exception::what()` to return something meaningful).

It's also possible to wrap the two in distinct catch clauses, but if the X object is passed by value, you still run the risk that the copy constructor or the move constructor throws (though in my experience move constructors rarely throw).

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible, because we are the direct caller of `f` and so it is us who constructs and destructs its argument and performs the call itself. Somewhere up the stack it would be indeed impossible to determine which particular function call down the stack threw the exception.

Comment: @radix, by the time the exception gets back to your stack frame, any information potentially identifying its source is gone. There is also no way for you to introduce side effects between the time the object is created in place and when the function is called that would allow you to determine whether the construction completed successfully. At best, you can wrap the two steps in different try-catch clauses, with the copy/move construction compromise.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yeah, sure, you can get as dirty as you want with your code and you can probably find a way to do it that will work on your machine, but I doubt that you'll find a *standard* way to do it without breaking up the creation and the call.